# Efficient way to store comments in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

With Google App Engine, an entity is limited to 1 MB in size. Say I have a blog system, and expect thousands of comments on each article, some paragraphs in lengths. Typically, without a limit, you'd just store all the comments in the same entity as the blog post. But here, there would be concerns about reaching the 1 MB limit.

The other possible way, though far less efficient, is to store each comment as a separate entity, but that would require several, several reads to get all comments instead of just 1 read to get the blog post and its comments (if they were in the same entity).

What's an efficient way to handle a case like this?

Comment: Store them as separate entities and use cache to avoid multiple reads and to increase speed.

Comment: @kichik cache seems like an unreliable solution, no? Maybe something more predictable, more constant. If for some reason the comments get wiped from the cache, I'll end up with a really really large bill at the end of the month

Comment: Pretty reliable, from my experience. But don't listen to me, profile both solutions with [appstats](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats).

Comment: @kichik another issue is that comments, in my case, can be edited and liked, like with Facebook comments. So comments will have to be modified perhaps often, which would not be ideal with memcache

Comment: Editing a multiple MB entity won't be fast either. Especially if the same entity will be edited multiple times a second. You can always delete a cache key or set a new value to it.

Comment: @mohabitar You could store "comment likes" in a separate table so that LIKEing a comment wouldn't touch the comment itself.  Since comments are supposed to be edited much less frequently than read, memcache could actually help here.

Answer (score 2):

If comments are threaded, storing them as separate entities might make sense.

If comments can be the target of voting, storing them as separate entities makes sense.

If comments can be edited, storing them as separate entities reduces contention, and avoids having to either do pessimistic locking on all comments, or risk situations where the last edit overwrites prior edits.

If you can page through comments, storing them as separate entities makes sense for multiple reasons, indexing being one.

Answer (score 1):

I have six suggestions:

1) Store the comments in separate entities. Use the NDB API, which has build in caching and cursors. So you can limit the query costs per view. You can use key only queries, ancestor and projection queries for fast access. See: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing

2) Seperate entities makes concurrency and indexing more easy.

3) Have a look at the Search API and the Prosepective Search API. If you have a lot of comments search will be important. Because of search you should use seperate entities for your comments, which makes it very easy to access the search results.

4) Processing seperate entities is also preferred, when you use tools like mapreduce for analyzing the comments.

5) And you can always optimize based on your experience with your blog engine and appstats. Is the datastore the real bottleneck or the number of instances used. I do not know your usecase, but you can also use the client (browser) to optimize and cache results.

6) And what about third party solutions for handling comments. See this article from Nick Johnson using Disqus javascript for comments and search in his app engine blog engine: http://blog.notdot.net/2009/10/Blogging-on-App-Engine-part-6-Comments-and-Search